# How do you create an array in vyper?

Tags: arrays, vyper

How do you create an array in vyper?

I want to create the array below but vyper is confusion.

```
Outcomes = [5, 500, 5000, 50000, 500000000, -1, -100, -1000, -10000, -100000, -500, -5000, -50000, -500000, -10000000, -50000000]
```

Answer (score 3):

Vyper is a [statically typed language](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#types), which means that the type of each variable must be specified when it is declared.

An array is cast by applying a subscript (`[]`) to a base type.  In your example, because some values are less than zero, the base type is `int128`. There are 16 values, so the final type is `int128[16]`.

```py
Outcomes: int128[16] = [5, 500, 5000, 50000, 500000000, -1, -100, -1000, -10000, -100000, -500, -5000, -50000, -500000, -10000000, -50000000]
```